# Select in laravel with 2 conditions and while

Tags: php, laravel, mysqli

Good afternoon, I have a problem in my system, I need to use 2 conditions in a select and then display all the records with while, but because I'm easy I'm picking up a little.

My Controller

```
public function index()
{
   $users = DB::select('select * from users where id = :id', ['id' => 1]);
   $id = $users->id;
   $chats = DB::table('chat')->where('idremetente', $id)->where('iddestino', $id)->get();

   $atual = date('m');

   $aniversariante = DB::select("select * from users where MONTH(nascimento) = '{$atual}'");


      return view('home', [
             'users' => $users,
             'aniversariante' => $aniversariante,
             'chats' => $chats,
         ]);
}
```

My View

```
@foreach($chats as $chat)
@endforeach
{{chat->id}}
```

Comment: @foreach($chats as $chat)
{{chat->id}}
@endforeach edit your view to this

Comment: This correct?  $chats = DB::table('chat')->where('idremetente', $users->id)->where('iddestino', $users-id)->get();

Comment: yeah but you need to make sure your view blade is correct

Comment: $users = DB::select('select * from users where id = :id', ['id' => 1]);
       $chats = DB::table('chat')->where('idremetente', $users->id)->where('iddestino', $users-id)->get();

Comment: what is the output?

Comment: return view('home', [
                 'users' => $users,
                 'aniversariante' => $aniversariante,
                 'chats' => $chats,
             ]);

Comment: When I leave like this:
$users = DB::select('select * from users where id = :id', ['id' => 1]);
$chats = DB::table('chat')->get();
It works.

But when I leave like this it does not work.                                                 
       $users = DB::select('select * from users where id = :id', ['id' => 1]);
       $chats = DB::table('chat')->where('idremetente', $users-id)->where('iddestino', $users-id)->get();

Answer (score 1):

`DB::select()` is for executing a raw statement, not the query builder.

If you want to use the query builder you need to use `DB::table()`:

```
$chats = DB::table('chat')->where('idremetente', $id)->where('iddestino', $id)->get();
```

And when using the query builder, you have to execute the query and fetch the results with `get()`.

Read the difference between [raw statements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#running-queries) and the [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries) in the docs.

Comment: I made the correction, how do I get the get value the way it is? Error:Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: This correct?  $chats = DB::table('chat')->where('idremetente', $users->id)->where('iddestino', $users-id)->get();

Answer (score 0):

> for used multiple  condition

```
$chats = DB::table('chat')->where('idremetente', $firstConditionValue)->where('iddestino', $secondConditionValue)->get();
```

Comment: I made the correction, how do I get the get value the way it is? Error:Trying to get property of non-object –

Answer (score 0):

To your controller

```
public function index()
{
$users = DB::table('user')->where('id', 1)->get();
$id = $users->id;
$chats = DB::table('chat')->where('idremetente', $id)->where('iddestino', $id)->get();

$atual = date('m');

$aniversariante = DB::table('user')->where('nascimento', $atual)->get();

  return view('home', compact('users','aniversariante','chats'));
}
```

And your view

```
@foreach($chats as $chat)
{{chat->id}}
@endforeach
```

Try this one

Comment: Exception
Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: My intention is to get the id of the user who is logged in to adminlte.